# How can I omit interactions using stargazer or xtable?

Tags: r, latex, regression, knitr, xtable

Is it possible to omit interactions in stargazer using the `omit` option?
Normally I would write the variable name into the `omit=c('varname')` but in the case of an interaction I do not know what to write. Any hints on that?
How do you solve this problem in other packages like `xtable`?

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}   
%Load dataset and run regression    

 << lm, echo=FALSE >>=   
 load('dataset.RData')  
 library(stargazer)  
 lm1 <- lm(y~ x + factor(v)*z ,data=dataset)  
 @


 << table_texstyle, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, results='asis' >>=  
 stargazer(lm1 ,omit=c('???'), omit.labels=c('Omitted interactions'),
      omit.yes.no = c("Yes", "No")))  
  @  
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to omit all interactions, try

```
stargazer(m1, omit = ":")
```

This works because `omit` argument is expecting a regular expression. This is a very powerful tool when filtering strings. See `?regexpr` or browse the `regex` tab here on Stackoverflow.