# Dummy variable with stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm doing an estimation using a lot of dummy variables. However I am not interested in the estimation coefficient of some dummy variable. I use them just for controling other variables. I just want to specify that I have used them

I would like to know if I could get a setting like the following by using stargazer: ?

```
                   Reg 1       Reg 2

| covariates 1  |     21***   20 *** 
                    (0.2)     (0.12)

| covariate 2   |     0.5     0.3***
                     (0.4)    (0.13)

|dummmy variable|    No        Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's  possible to have this setting using 3 options in stargazer namely,

omit
omit.labels 
omit.yes.no=c("Yes","No")

[here is the reference](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf).

The code would sound like: 
`stargazer(Reg1, Reg2, omit="dummyVariable", omit.label="dummy variable", omit.yes.no=c("Yes", "No"))`

Here are some useful references :

[omit interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445400/how-can-i-omit-interactions-using-stargazer-or-xtable)

[knitr package. Very useful with stargazer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937026/table-placement-with-stargazer-and-knitr)